# evolution notification for folders

Tags: evolution, gmail

I am using evolution mail client from my gmail account. Whenever a mail arrives in INBOX I get notification but if the mail arrives in some other folder then I don't receive notification. How can I receive notification for all my folder, even junk folder too.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Right click on said folder
- Left click on "Properties"
- Ceckbox "Always check for new mail in this folder"

[image: Folder Properties]